# Tail -f the most recent log file

Tags: shell, ls, tail

In a few spots I got this to work

```
ls -rt /path/to/log/file/ | tail -1 | xargs tail -f
```

But I can't figure out why it won't always work
(This is quick fix until I get the log rolling fixed here)

Answer (score 17):

### Sort command and THE *most recent  log file*

Why using `-r` (reverse sort order) than reaching end of output with `tail`?

Using normal sort order and take first entry would be quicker!

```
tail -f `/bin/ls -1td /path/to/log/file/*| /usr/bin/head -n1`
```

or

```
tail -f $(/bin/ls -1t /path/to/log/file/* | /bin/sed q)
```

work fine.

Nota: I like to use `sed` because this command is present in `/bin`, maybe before `/usr` are mounted.

```
tail -f `/bin/ls -1tr /path/to/log/file/* | /bin/sed -ne '$p'`
```

would work but, as already said: inversing sort order, than dropping whole ouput for using only last entry is not *a real good idea* ;-)

**Warning**, in last directory, `*` have to not match a directory, or else command `tail` won't know how to open it.

#### Same but using `find` for searching for most recent file:

```
read -a file < <(
    find /tmp 2>/dev/null -type f -mmin +-1 -mmin -10 -printf "%Ts %p\n" |
    sort -rn)
tail -f ${file[1]}
```

**Note:**

- the `-mmin +-1` ensure to not list bad timed files: *in the futur*.
- `read` is builtin, create an array and prevent the use of `head -n1| cut -d \  -f2`
- `-mmin -10` could be changed or suppressed, but this prevent long sort process.

### But tail support to watch about more than one file:

Try to open two shell console and try this:

In 1st console:

```
user@host[pts/1]:~$ touch /tmp/file_{1,2,3}
user@host[pts/1]:~$ tail -f /tmp/file_{1,2,3}
==> /tmp/file_1 <==

==> /tmp/file_2 <==

==> /tmp/file_3 <==
```

in second one, while keeping 1st console visible, hit many time:

```
user@host[pts/2]:~$ tee -a /tmp/file_$((RANDOM%3+1)) <<<$RANDOM
25285
user@host[pts/2]:~$ tee -a /tmp/file_$((RANDOM%3+1)) <<<$RANDOM
16381
user@host[pts/2]:~$ tee -a /tmp/file_$((RANDOM%3+1)) <<<$RANDOM
19766
user@host[pts/2]:~$ tee -a /tmp/file_$((RANDOM%3+1)) <<<$RANDOM
3053
```

1st console could look like:

```
==> /tmp/file_2 <==
25285

==> /tmp/file_1 <==
16381
19766

==> /tmp/file_3 <==
3053
```

...

### In the idea of SO question, but time based, multi files

By using `find` command, we could watch on last minutes modified files `-mmin` or last days `-mtime`:

```
find /path/to/logdir -type f -mmin -10 -exec tail -f {} +
```

for watching for logfiles modified last 10 minutes.

**Note:**

- Have a look at `man tail`, about

  - `-F` option for long time watch
  - `-q` option for not printing file names

#### Fancy formatting

```
find /path/to/logdir -type f -mmin -10 -exec tail -f {} + |
    sed -une 's/^==> .path.to.logdir.\(.*\) <==$/\1             /;ta;bb;
               :a;s/^\(.\{12\}\) *$/\1: /;h;bc;
               :b;G;s/^\(..*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/p;:c;'
```

Where you could modify `.path.to.logdir.` and change `12` for more suitable length.

For sample, keeping our two console, stop 1st and try

```
user@host[pts/1]:~$ find /tmp/ -type f -mtime -1 -name 'file_?' -exec tail -f {} + |
    sed -une 's/^==> .tmp.\(.*\) <==$/\1             /;ta;bb;
        :a;s/^\(.\{12\}\) *$/\1: /;h;bc;
        :b;G;s/^\(..*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/p;:c;'
file_2      :  25285
file_1      :  16381
file_1      :  19766
file_3      :  3053
```

than in second console, hit again some

```
user@host[pts/2]:~$ tee -a /tmp/file_$((RANDOM%3+1)) <<<$RANDOM
```

Answer (score 6):

This will not work unless you are in `/path/to/log/file`, because `ls` gives you only the name of the file and `tail -f` won't find it. If you put a `*` in the end of the `ls` it will give you full paths:

```
ls -rt /var/log/apache2/* | tail -1 | xargs tail -f
```

Comment: why `-r` and `tail` (who implie to read whole stream)?? Instead of `/bin/ls -t | head -1`! This is not only simplier to axplain, but  also quicker to execute!

Comment: Thanks. I would love to package the above as a bash function that takes a regular expression like `'/var/log/apache2/*'` (using single quotes so that it does not get expanded) and then performs the exact same action. Could you help with that?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to use zsh and take advantage of the [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `om` to sort by modification time (most recent first) and `[1]` to retain only the first match.

```
tail -f /path/to/log/directory/*(om[1])
```

If you don't have zsh, install it. If you really don't want to install zsh, it's not too bad with `ls`, provided that your file names don't contain any special characters (anything nonprintable is calling for trouble here), which should be ok for log files. Note that [as Paylo Almeida already remarked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83962/tail-f-the-most-recent-log-file/83968#83968) you can't just use the output of `ls /path/to/log/directory` since that displays paths that are relative to `/path/to/log/directory`. You can change to that directory first:

```
cd /path/to/log/directory
tail -f "$(ls -t | head -n 1)"
```

Or you can add the path:

```
tail -f "/path/to/log/directory/$(ls -t /path/to/log/directory | head -n 1)"
```

Or you can get `ls` to print full paths:

```
tail -f "$(ls -t /path/to/log/directory/* | head -n 1)"
```

The `tail` command will keep following the same file forever, even if a more recent log file is created afterwards. If you want to automatically switch to a different file, you need a more sophisticated approach, where you detect new files and start a new instance of `tail` on the new file. Under Linux, you can use the [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) interface.

```
while true; do
  tail -n +1 -f /path/to/log/directory/*(om[1])
  inotifywait -qq -e create /path/to/log/directory
  kill $!
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to the event logs directory and give **tail -f *** to view all the recent logs.

Comment: That is not at all what the question asked.