# Grep a string from file

Tags: shell-script, grep

I have 5 filenames created inside a folder for one operation.The filenames are in the following format.

```
ES_currentdate_currenttime_processid_uniqueid.log
```

I want to read the status from the latest created file in that path.

The way I form the filename in shell script is:

```
$ filename=ES_*_uniqueid.log
$ echo grep "##status##XRB##" $HOME/log/$filename | sort -u` "
```

When I `grep` it reads the status from all 5 files and echoes it. I want the string to be `grep` only from the latest file that got created.

Could some one provide a solution?

Comment: Can you please show the actual names of a couple of the files? Need to see the timestamp format.

Comment: You was needed to put only one file to `grep` input and that file should be the last modified; [`slm`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85938/grep-a-string-from-file/85943#85943) did it :)

Answer (score 2):

So long as the files were written in chronological order the names of the files doesn't really matter. Just use `tail -1` to get the last file in a listing of the files and that should always be the latest file:

```
$ filename=ES_*_uniqueid.log
$ grep "##status##XRB##" $(ls -tr $filename | tail -1)
```

This will run the sub-command `ls -tr $filename | tail -1` which will return a single result, the most recent file. This file will then be grepped for strings matching `##status##XRB##`.

Answer (score 0):

In zsh ([explanations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83962/tail-f-the-most-recent-log-file/84037#84037):

```
grep "##status##XRB##" ~/log/ES_*.log(om[1])
```

If the dates are in a sensible format (YYYYmmdd_HHMMSS), then the lexicographic order on the file names corresponds to the chronological order. So in ksh or bash, you can put the names of the matching files in an array: the file you're after will be the last array element.

```
logs=(~/log/ES_*.log)
grep "##status##XRB##" "${logs[${#logs}-1]}"
```

With only a POSIX shell (e.g. `/bin/sh`), you can use the positional parameters.

```
grep_last_match () {
  eval set -- \"\${$#}\"
  grep "##status##XRB##" "$1"
}
grep_last_match ~/logs/ES_*.log
```